# "Но пока что увы"

Tags: пунктуация

Как правильно расставить знаки препинания?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Думаю, что здесь междометие "увы" использовано в качестве сказуемого. Поэтому знаков не нужно совсем. Или поставьте интонационное тире: Но пока что - увы!

Answer (score 2):

Я тоже за тире — оно тут просится.